EmbeddedView context. Passing observable
I have a templateRef:
@ViewChild('myTemplate', { read: TemplateRef, static: true })
    myTemplate!: TemplateRef<unknown>;

and viewContainerRef:
@ViewChild('vcr', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
    vcr!: ViewContainerRef;

then I create embedded view:
const newTemp = this.myTemplate.createEmbeddedView(
            null
            this.vcr.injector
        );

I add context:
newTemp.context = {
            observ: this.subject$.pipe(
                tap(() => 
                    console.log('context passed');
                ),
            ),
        };

and insert it:
this.vcr.insert(newTemp);

my html template looks like this:
<ng-container #vcr>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #myTemplate let-observ="observ" let-data="data">
    <div>Data: {{ data }}</div>
    <div> Obs data: {{ observ | async }} </div>
</ng-template>

Data appears just fine but the subscription won't even fire and there is nothing in the console.
I need to pass context in the component.

Assuming you are using Subject
If the subject values arrive before the subscription has occurred in the template, subscribing late to the subject means it misses the previous event
Use BehaviourSubject instead of subject
subject$ = new BehaviorSubject('Default value');

